# Instagram api login button in flying popup window

Tags: instagram-api

I am building app/website for customer with content from their instagram account (info and media).
Using instagram api login button by clicking on this button the customer Log into Instagram via a Pop-Up window with Javascript. After authentication he receive the acccess token, that used to make API endpoint calls.

THE JS CODE

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

        var accessToken = null; //the access token is required to make any endpoint calls, http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

        var authenticateInstagram = function(instagramClientId, instagramRedirectUri, callback) {

            //the pop-up window size, change if you want
            var popupWidth = 700,
                popupHeight = 500,
                popupLeft = (window.screen.width - popupWidth) / 2,
                popupTop = (window.screen.height - popupHeight) / 2;

            //the url needs to point to instagram_auth.php
            var popup = window.open('instagram_auth.php', 'thePopup', 'width='+popupWidth+',height='+popupHeight+',left='+popupLeft+',top='+popupTop+'');

            popup.onload = function() {

                //open authorize url in pop-up
                if(window.location.hash.length == 0) {
                    popup.open('https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id='+instagramClientId+'&redirect_uri='+instagramRedirectUri+'&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code', '_self');
                }
                console.log('000');

                //an interval runs to get the access token from the pop-up
                var interval = setInterval(function() {
                    
                    try {
                        //check if hash exists
                        if(popup.location.hash.length) {
                            //hash found, that includes the access token
                            clearInterval(interval);
                            accessToken = popup.location.hash.slice(14); //slice #access_token= from string
                            console.log(accessToken);
                            popup.close();
                            if(callback != undefined && typeof callback == 'function') callback();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(evt) {
                        //permission denied
                    }

                }, 100);
               
            }

        };

        function login_callback() {

            alert("You are successfully logged in! Access Token: "+accessToken);

        }

        function login() {
            authenticateInstagram(
                'XXXX', //instagram client ID
                'https://sample.com/account/instegramlogin', //instagram redirect URI
                login_callback //optional - a callback function
            );

            return false;

        }

    </script>
```

THE LOGIN BUTTON

```html
<a href="#" onclick="login()">Log into Instagram</a>
```

So in the login process in the popup window the final URL its like:
https://sample.com/account/instegramlogin?code=XXXXXXXXX...#_
And the popup close when the # appear in the popup window URL if(popup.location.hash.length) {... popup.close()...

The scenario above its working well only for this authorize URL (without the "third_part") for must customers:
[https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id='+instagramClientId+'&redirect_uri='+instagramRedirectUri+'&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code](https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=%27+instagramClientId+%27&redirect_uri=%27+instagramRedirectUri+%27&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code)

But for some customers the authorize URL include the
"third_part" in the URL:
[https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/third_party?client_id='+instagramClientId+'&redirect_uri='+instagramRedirectUri+'&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code](https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/third_party?client_id=%27+instagramClientId+%27&redirect_uri=%27+instagramRedirectUri+%27&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code)

So the popup didn't close by this code.

```js
try {
                        //check if hash exists
                        if(popup.location.hash.length) {
                            //hash found, that includes the access token
                            clearInterval(interval);
                            accessToken = popup.location.hash.slice(14); //slice #access_token= from string
                            console.log(accessToken);
                            popup.close();
                            if(callback != undefined && typeof callback == 'function') callback();
                        }
                    }
```

The window popup didn't recognized when the authorize URL include the "third_part" text?

When adding this code to the code above to check if "third_part" text included in the window popup url

```js
 if(popup.location.href.indexOf("third_party") > -1) {
                         popup.close();
                     }
```

I receive JS error "Uncaught DOMException: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent."

Trying different codes but didn't help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.